# Topology of a free group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, geometric-group-theory

I wonder is there any general properties/ restrictions to the possible topologies of a free group (to make it a topological group ofc). More generally do such restrictions exist for any group written as presentation?

Comment: I don't think one can say a lot in general. Plenty of topological groups admit a free subgroup, typically dense, and this provides many of group topologies on free groups. Already $\mathbf{Z}$ itself admits $2^c$ group topologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interesting "restriction" is that if you want the topology to be locally compact Hausdorff or come from a complete metric then the topology will have to be the discrete topology. This follow from results in *Continuity of homomorphisms* by Dudley, where he proves "automatic continuity" results for certain types of groups.

A slight simplification is that if we have $G \to F$ a group homomorphism, where $F$ is free with the discrete topology and $G$ has a nice topology, like being locally compact Hausdorff, then the homomorphism is automatically continuous.

Using this we can suppose that $(F,\tau)$ is one of these nice topologies. Then $$Id:(F, \tau) \to F$$
is continuous by Dudley's automatic continuity results, which means that $\tau$ had to be the discrete topoology.

A consequence of this is that $F_\mathfrak{c}$, the free group on continuum many generators, can not be made into a Polish group. But $F_\mathfrak{c}$ obviously has quotients which can be made Polish, the any countable quotient or the group of real numbers.

---

Note that $F_n$ can be given non-locally compact Hausdorff topolgies by embedding $F_n$ into nice groups like Lie groups and be dense in them(related to YCor's comment). These topolgies will "look like" $\mathbb Q$.

With that in mind there are finitely generated groups which have no Hausdorff group topology besides the discrete topology(hence quotients of free groups). The paper [*On topologizable and non-topologizable groups*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7895) actually proves that there are lots satisfying even stronger properties.

Answer (score 2):

Free groups are residually finite: for all $g\in F$ there exists a homomorphism $\phi_g: F\rightarrow H_g$ where $H_g$ is finite and $\phi_g(g)\neq1$. What the following says is that we can equip $F$ (and more generally, any residually finite group) with a natural topology, the "profinite topology", and construct a group, its "profinite completion" $\widehat{F}$, such that $F\hookrightarrow \widehat{F}$ is an monomorphism of topological groups (so the topology on $F$ is inherited from the topology on $\widehat{F}$).

The *profinite topology* of a group $G$ takes as a basis of open sets the finite index open subgroups of $G$. Then $G$ is residually finite if and only if its profinite topology is Hausdorff.

The *profinite completion* $\widehat{G}$ of a group $G$ is the inverse limit of the groups $G/N$, where $N$ runs through the normal subgroups in $G$ of finite index (these normal subgroups are partially ordered by inclusion, which translates into an inverse system of natural homomorphisms between the quotients:
$$\{f_{i,j}: G/N_j \to G/N_i \mid i, j \in I, i \le j\}.$$
Formally, the profinite completion is as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\widehat{G}&:=
\lim_{\leftarrow}{G/N_i}\\
&= \left\{ (gN_i)_{i \in I} \in \prod_{i \in I} G/N_i \:\:\middle|\:\: f_{i, j} (g_j) = g_i \text{ for all } j \ge i \right\}.
\end{align*}
$$
Bestow on $\widehat{G}$ a topology as follows: give each $G/N$ the discrete topology, the product the product topology, and the projective limit the restriction topology.
Note that there is a natural homomorphism $\phi: G\rightarrow \widehat{G}$. Then $G$ is residually finite if and only if $\phi$ is an injection.

Suppose $G$ is residually finite (e.g. take $G$ to be free), and equip it with the profinite topology. Then $\phi$ is continuous. As it is an embedding, $G$ inherits the profinite topology from its profinite completion $\widehat{G}$.

---

People care about profinite things. For example, Grothendieck asked, roughly, the following question: does $\widehat{G_1}\cong\widehat{G_2}$ imply $G_1\cong G_2$ (in the natural way)? The answer is no, as proven in
Martin R. Bridson and Fritz J. Grunewald, *Grothendieck’s problems concerning proﬁnite completions and representations of groups*, Ann. Math., **160** (2004), 359–373
[(link)](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v160-n1-p08.pdf).